# Using jQuery in HTML select when it's open and not

Tags: jquery, select

I'm trying to do some kind of poor man's two column implementation using HTML's select tag and JavaScript's/jQuery's click and 'select change' event handlers.

Purpose is easy but implementation ain't.

So, case goes like this.

1. user clicks an empty select html component and data is fetch from server.
2. when user wants to select from data item in select tag he clicks select html component
3. select html component opens and it show rows read so, that it contain data from two arrays: number identifier, a short splitter like ' ---- ', and then description of that number identifier which is text
4. when select html tag is open user can select a row using mouse click or enter key. When select is open all rows are like '12321213 --- this is description' 
   e) after user has selected the row he wants select tag's open list is closed and in select tag's input field should be only number identifier like '12321213' and rest of row is stripped away. 
   f) when user selects that '12321213' from select tag and it is open it should show the whole row like in selecting phase like '12321213 --- this is description'

I have tried solved this using JavaScript/jQuery and two arrays containing same data with two fields number identifier and description. Second array has been a storage to restore and contain both fields (number and description) when they are needed to shown.

My code has been like following: (Tasklist is Select Option list)

```
("#TaskList").click(function (event) {

    var index = $('#TaskList option:selected').val();
    console.log(' click ' + disableOptions);
    if (disableOptions === true) {  // This fetch data using ajax from serverside
        disableOptions = false;
        $("#TaskList option").remove();
        $('#TaskList').attr("disabled", "disabled");

        $('<input />').attr('type', 'hidden')
                      .attr('name', 'GETTASKS')
                      .attr('value', 'GETTASKS')
                      .appendTo('#workForm');
        $('#workForm').submit();
    }
    else {  // This restores whole row from second array containing number and description
        $("#TaskList").html($("#CombinedLists").html());
        $("#TaskList option[value='" + index + "']").attr('selected', 'selected');
    }
});

$(function () {
    $('select').on('change', function (e) {
         console.log(' select on change ');
          // Getting selected index of select option list
          var index = $('#TaskList option:selected').val();
          // Getting text of selected row
          var row = $("#TaskList option[value='" + index + "']").text();
          // If row contains ' ---' if means option window is closed and only number shown
          if (row.indexOf(' ---') > -1) {
              longText = false;
              row = row.substring(0, row.indexOf(' '));
              $('#TaskList option:selected').text(row);
          }
          else { // Option windows is opened and both number and description is shown
              longText = true;
              row = $("#CombinedLists option[value='" + index + "']").text();
              $("#TaskList option[value='" + index + "']").text(row);
          }
      })
      .change();
});
```

So, the problem seems to be click event and situation where number or/and description is shown in opened select option list. Like I mention when Option window is open both number and description is shown and when row is selected from Option windows and window is closed only number identifier is hown in select HTML tag's input field.

How this should be coded? Have tried quite long but didn't succeeded. My application is ASP.NET MVC 5 based using Bootstrap 3 so I can't use every plugins that seems to know how to handle this kind of functionality. So, like to code a JavaScript/jQuery solution but how?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you set the description on the title attribute so when they hover over it, a tooltip shows.

Also, you may look into the jQuery Autocomplete. You can show different text on search vs select.

Comment: Do you mean title attribute in select's option attribute or what? Can you you give an example how to handle it?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/2L9hpa27/
Notice when you hover over the options in the dropdown list, the tooltip appears.

Comment: Yes, worth of trying..but one thing is missing and that's when user moves with arrow keys then there are no Title available. Is it possible to get it?

Comment: Tool-tip only happens in mouse-over event. That's native property. You could explore jquery tooltip plugins.